# Question about regular expressions in computer theort

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions, finite-automata

I have the following regular expression

$$(ΣΣ)^∗ = \{w\mid w \text{ is a string of even length}\}.$$

The problem is that I don't quiet agree with the description of the regular expression. It is indeed a string of even length, but strings like 1000 are not allowed. $x^*$ means all the strings in the form xxxxxx... , but there is no way you can get 1000 with something in the form $(x)^*$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In formal languages and automata theory sigma $\Sigma$ is used to represent the set of all characters in your language.  So if the characters of your language are "$0$" and "$1$" then you can treat $\Sigma$ as $(0|1)$.

Your example then expands to $((0|1)(0|1))*$ which will match "1000".